# Can someone give one exact example of webview implementation in android

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

Hi I am developing android application using `WebView` implementation.

I followed the [official android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html).

I am not getting errors when building my project in eclipse, but when running the application :

> the application has stopped working unexpectedly

Comment: plz add your logcat error....

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your Java file should be like this:

```
public class WebViewSampleActivity extends Activity {
     WebView wb;
    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);      
        wb=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);        
        wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wb.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        wb.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        wb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        wb.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        wb.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);           
        wb.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
        wb.loadUrl("http://www.examplefoo.com");        
    }
}
```

Your xml file should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Use the following in your manifest after `<uses-sdk><uses-sdk/>`:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Hi i have do the above mentioned things now im getting an error " conversion to dalvik version fail"

Comment: There could be some issues with your emulator then. Try running it on another AVD. If it still doesn't work, please post your Logcat.

Comment: Hi i tried with 2 AVD's one is android 2.2 and another is 3.2 bt still im getting the error.Attaching is the log cat please help me asap...

Comment: Unless you post your logcat errors, there isn't much I can do.

Comment: Hey im unable to get any logcat. tat was earlier project logcat. how can i fix this issue.

Comment: Logcat starts the moment you hit run in your eclipse. Cross-check once. There's no way Logcat can't run once you start running the application. Click on Window > Show View > Logcat

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6083/discussion-between-andriod-murali-and-rahul)

Answer (score 3):

[image: Android WebView loadurl example]

[Android WebView Example](https://androidride.com/android-webview-example-tutorial-kotlin-java-download-source-code/)

WebView used to show webpages in our app. Let's make a WebView and load any website

provide permission in **AndroidManifest.XML**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**MainActivity.Java**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
private WebView webview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

webview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
//loads androidride homepage to webview
webview.loadUrl("https://www.androidride.com");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
    LinearLayout root = new LinearLayout(this);
root.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

WebView wv = new WebView(this);
wv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)); 
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 

wv.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
root.addView(wv);

setContentView(root);
```

Put this code in your onCreate-Method.
And don't forget to set the Permission Internet in Android Manifest.

Answer (score 1):

WebView is a view that display web pages inside your application. You can also specify HTML string and can show it inside your application using WebView.

Tutorial with Example: http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/09/android-webview-tutorial-with-examples.html

activity_main.xml file

```
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

MainActivity.java File

```
import android.webkit.WebView;

...

webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.viralandroid.com");
```

Comment: Your code does not work. Error: cannot find symbol class webView. You have to use `WebView` not `webView` ...

Answer (score 1):

Xml file

```
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

   android:id="@+id/myweb"

   android:layout_width="fill_parent"

   android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

java file

```
 WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myweb);

 web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

 web.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);

 web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

 web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

 web.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

 web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

 web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

 web.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);

 web.loadUrl("https://www.technolifehacker.com");

 web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  class WebViewClass extends WebViewClient {
        final  ProgressBar loadProgress;
        final  WebView wv;

        WebViewClass(WebView webView, ProgressBar progressBar) {
            this.wv = webView;
            this.loadProgress = progressBar;
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            wv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            loadProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            view.clearCache(true);
        }

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            wv.loadData("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>" + "<center>" + getString(R.string.erroopsproblem) + ".</center>", "text/html", "UTF-8");
        }
    }
```

Now use this class on onCreate() like

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        wv.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.setScrollBarStyle(View.VISIBLE);
        wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        wv.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        wv.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        wv.loadUrl(Dest);
        wv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClass(wv, loadProgress));
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @ghost answer, if you want your web-view to be fully functional like a browser i.e. you can go forward and back then you need to override onBackPressed method of your activity like below

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
if (webView.canGoBack()) {
    webView.goBack();
  } else {
    super.onBackPressed();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You must

1. Create a Layout XML file for example 'test.xml'
2. Create a class that inherited Activity for example 'wvtutorial
3. In OnCreate method of its life cycle, create an instance of WebView , for example 'wview' , by initialized value null
4. And other