# Eclipse Android : How to show a htm file in an app

Tags: android, html, eclipse

I want to program an app for my school. Therefore I want to create an activity in which I can display a htm file of the school homepage. I dont want the app to open the browser, but the app should display the content of the file inside the app.
I hope you know what I mean.
For example if there is a link to the file : 
http://www.example.net/fileadmin/XYZ/Aktuelles/Schwarzes_Brett/Vertretungsplaene/Vertr-Pl-Mo.htm
(Do not be surprised, im German.) What do I have to do that it works as I want it. Thanks for help! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can someone give one exact example of webview implementation in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614553/can-someone-give-one-exact-example-of-webview-implementation-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

You can use WebView to load your html file locally or from any url.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.plc.asnad.test;
import android.app.*;
import android.webkit.*;
import android.os.*;
import com.plc.asnad.*;
import java.net.*;

public class wvtutorial extends Activity 
{
WebView wview = null; // 1 - Instance of Webview is initialize by null value

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // in lifecycle of vwtutorial activity and in OnCreate method , start to work 
    // with webview

    // start to inflate and parsing layout xml , for access to view and viewgroups
    // componnents
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    // access to webview by casting the parsed views from layout xml

    wview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.mywview);
      // create regular string for conatructing html body file  
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    str.append("<html>").append("\n");
    str.append("<head>").append("\n");
    str.append("<title>").append("mytest").append("<\title>").append("\n");
    str.append("</head>").append("\n");
    str.append("<body>").append("\n");
    str.append("<b>hello webview</b>").append("\n");
    str.append("</body>").append("\n");
    str.append("</html>");
    // set enable javascript feature of webview
    wview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    // finally, load html body stringed into wview and render and show it
    wview.loadData(str.toString(),"text/html","utf-8");
    // wview.loadurl("file:///android_assets/sample.html");

} 

}
```

You can use this tutorial , that have a java file and a layout XML : 
http://uploadboy.me/wacaif2eagoj/wviewtutorial.zip.html