# How to convert responsive website to android app

Tags: android, wordpress, android-layout, responsive-design

I recently developed a website with WordPress. It has a completely responsive template. I want to make an android app for that website. Is there is shortcut which I can use to develop the app? I mean can I convert the website to mobile app?

I know my question is not related to coding but I really need some help.!

Answer (score 1):

## Create MyAppWebViewClient.java File

```
package com.example.test;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("websitename.com")) {
            return false;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

### Write Code In MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    WebView mwebview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mwebview=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webVieww);
        WebSettings websetting=mwebview.getSettings();
        websetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mwebview.loadUrl("http://websitename.com");
        //mwebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mwebview.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mwebview.canGoBack()) {
            mwebview.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

#### put in activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webVieww"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "easier" way you can use is creating a new application in android with only a `WebView` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614553/can-some-one-give-one-exact-example-of-webview-implementaiton-in-android) you can find an easy demostration on how it works and in this link you have the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

PS: this is the easy way, if your site is responsive and can be easily adapted to a phone site looking like an app, use this way, but is not reccomended to develop a "site app". If you have the mobile site, your app should have something more than it. like the menu, some login features, something like this.

I suggest you to develop a full application, if possible. You can use all your site's images and patterns, but it will be different.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If still relevant, there's a service I've recently found allowing to convert/wrapp  any responsive website to an android apk: [applika.me](https://www.applika.me/) enjoy.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this using plugin [Apppresser](https://wordpress.org/plugins/apppresser/). This plugin create App from wordpress site. The basic plugin is free you can use it easily.

Answer (score -2):

**Plugins for WordPress that create app from WordPress site:**
1. Plain WebView App 
2. PhoneGap Webview App 
3. AppPresser 
4. Worona 
5. Project App Plugin 
6. Native App 
7. Bobile 
8. WordPress REST API