# Best way to encapsulate HTML5 responsive web site in Android App to avoid some user interactions with browser

Tags: android, html, jasonette

We have a responsive web application that is currently used on an android device (zebra TC20) through the Chrome browser.
Since we have to limit some actions by users such as the ability to open multiple tabs and force them to log out rather than close the browser, we're considering the possibility to embed the site in an android app.

At the moment the best candidate is Jasonette (http://docs.jasonette.com/android/) because of its simplicity, but I wanted to know if there are other solutions that are equally simple but that bring additional benefits to be considered when choosing.

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614553/can-someone-give-one-exact-example-of-webview-implementation-in-android

Comment: @AkshayKatariya thanks for the reply. We are .NET programmers for which Jasonette seems better as a solution because it mainly requires JSON knowledge that we already own to start developing applications for the android world without having to acquire additional specific skills.