# Opening Links in a Webview

Tags: android, webview, hyperlink

In the moment I try, that links are getting opened in my App.
I read many posts how to do it and nothing worked for me. This is the code which I'm in currently using and which did not work:

```
 wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can someone give one exact example of webview implementation in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614553/can-someone-give-one-exact-example-of-webview-implementation-in-android)

Comment: Its not, mine is about Deep Linking of Links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Firstly you need to add Internet Permission to `AndroidMainfest.xml` file

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application ...
</manifest>
```

Here's WebView sample code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   Button b1;
   EditText ed1;

   private WebView wv1;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
      ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

      wv1=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
      wv1.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());

      b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            String url = ed1.getText().toString();

            wv1.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            wv1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wv1.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
            wv1.loadUrl(url);
         }
      });
   }

   private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
      @Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
         view.loadUrl(url);
         return true;
      }
   }
}
   }
```

Read more about WebView in the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview) and here's a [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_webview_layout.htm) maybe help you

Comment: Thanks for your awnser! Bit it did not helped me! If I am clicking on a link it is still opening it in my default browser :( and not in my webview in my App. What am I doing wrong?