# User ACTION_VIEW Intent to open URL In APP

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I am new to android and working on small project where i am using

```
   customerSupport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(config.tawkto));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
            }
        });
```

to open my  `public static final String tawkto = "https://tawk.to/chat/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/default";`

So how can I make sure my **config.tawkto** will open in my own app, not in another browser.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you have to use [WebView](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview), Follow this steps,

1. Create New Activity and use `WebView` in that activity
2. Load your config.tawkto Url in that WebView
3. Redirect to that WebView Activity, in your case when user click on `customerSupport` button.

Comment: visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614553/can-someone-give-one-exact-example-of-webview-implementation-in-android for WebView Example